# Add hours based on country

Tags: r, facebook

So i have a column displaying the country of origin from each Facebook post.I also have the time creation of the post.What i want to do is to add 3 hours for every Arabian post. Then i want to add 5 hours for Russian posts.Let's say i have 12 countries with 12 different time zones that need to be added.

allCountries <- c("Arabia" , "Argentina", "Brazil", "Global", "India","Malaysia","Mexico","Poland","Sweden","Turkey","MaxTurkey","Ukraine","US")

Sorry it's in R language

Comment: what language? if in a database you could use CASE maybe.... case when country ='somecountry' then time+X else time end....etc